# Can someone show me a complete sample of using a simple type library in a C++ application?

Tags: com, typelib

I have an old application written in C++ using Visual Studio 2008 that uses COM to use a DLL written in C# using Visual Studio 2012 to display Crystal Reports reports.  The VS2012 library is much more complicated than it needs to be, and the method used to access it from the C++ application is also overly complicated.  So, as an exercise, I want to write a much simpler VS2012 library to display the reports and then use that library from a C++ application.

I am beginning with a trivial library and trying to make sure I can use it.  I am not succeeding.  Here is the library's code:

```
namespace ComVisibleSample
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("83F56EB3-086E-4F81-9FD4-A89ECB708F3E")]
    [ProgId("ComVisibleSample.ComVisibleSample")]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IComVisibleSample))]
    public class ComVisibleSample : IComVisibleSample
    {
        public ComVisibleSample() {}
        public int DoSomething()
        {
            return 42;
        }
    }
}
```

I created a C++ console application in VS2012 and added a #import directive to import this library.  That compiled successfully.  Here is the .tlh file that it generated:

```
// Created by Microsoft (R) C/C++ Compiler Version 11.00.50727.1 (3903bee7).
//
// c:\rad-con tools\trunk\crystalreportssample\consoleapplication1\debug\comvisiblesample.tlh
//
// C++ source equivalent of Win32 type library C:\Rad-Con Tools\trunk\ComVisibleSample\bin\Debug\ComVisibleSample.tlb
// compiler-generated file created 04/23/19 at 12:48:46 - DO NOT EDIT!

#pragma once
#pragma pack(push, 8)

#include <comdef.h>

namespace ComVisibleSample {

//
// Forward references and typedefs
//

struct __declspec(uuid("adffb523-f1ef-4967-9e96-c3ad943d5d97"))
/* LIBID */ __ComVisibleSample;
struct /* coclass */ ComVisibleSample;

//
// Type library items
//

struct __declspec(uuid("83f56eb3-086e-4f81-9fd4-a89ecb708f3e"))
ComVisibleSample;
    // interface _Object

} // namespace ComVisibleSample

#pragma pack(pop)
```

No .tli file was generated.

Here's the program where I'm trying to use the type library:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#import "C:\Rad-Con Tools\trunk\ComVisibleSample\bin\Debug\ComVisibleSample.tlb"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ComVisibleSample::ComVisibleSample sampleObject();
    int result = sampleObject.DoSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the call to DoSomething(), the program compiles.  But with that line in, the compiler complains that left of .DoSomething() must be a class/struct/union.

What do I have to do to get this program and library to play happily together?

Comment: Remove IComVisibleSample (it doesn't seem to be define in C++, and you don't need it maybe, in fact it depends what you really want to do) and set ClassInterfaceType to AutoDual.

Comment: You'll have little hope of making the rather large number of existing examples work for you without the TLI file.  Looks like you forgot to apply [ComVisible(true)] to the IComVisibleSample interface declaration.

Comment: Changing to AutoDual did not help.  I suspect Hans is correct.

Comment: And I spent a fair amount of time on Google trying to find one of those existing examples.  I found a lot of things talking about one thing or another that I need to do, but I did not find any that show a complete, working example.

Comment: I told you to remove IComVisibleSample *and* set ClassInterfaceType to AutoDual, not just change AutoDual. You can use IComVisibleSample if you know what you're doing but since you don't give its definition and its not in the .tlh, one easy solution is to not use a custom interface.

Comment: I found [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828736/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-from-native-visual-c-code-in-visual-studio-n), walked through it, and it worked.  I should be able to extrapolate from that to get what I need.